# How to add icons to the link using twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image]I wanted to add icons to my links using twitter bootstrap.

I have input fields in as shown in snapshot. I want everything should look same including the box and icon but instead of a input box is it possible that i can have a link.

PS : I don't want a select box. I want a link with a icon just like i can have a select box with a icon.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Could you mock something up in an image editor or whatever and post the image to demonstrate what you are looking for?

Comment: can you plz some code ??

Comment: do you want a hyperlink with an icon

Comment: Yes i want a hyperlink with an icon :))

Comment: @SaurabhKumar plz check solution and jsfiddle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Check jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/zqNzk/show)
This way you can use icond with links

```
<li><a href=""><i class=" icon-pencil icon-2x"></i>About Us</a></li>
```